# Cant get 2 divs next to each other but on different sides of the page

Tags: html, css

I cant get 2 divs on the same line but one is aligned right.

```css
.container>* {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .85);
}

.menulinks {
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blueviolet;
  float: left;
}

.menulinks:hover {
  color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="assets/logo.png" width="150">
  </div>

  <div align="right">
    <a href="photos.html" class="menulinks">Photos</a>
    <a href="about.html" class="menulinks">About</a>
    <a href="socials.html" class="menulinks">Socials</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

It was working before when I had tables and stuff but I thought this would be easier. They are on the same line but the links just won't align to the right,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers are good in specifying that you can achieve this with flexbox.

My answer shows another flexbox approach. If you define `margin-left: auto` on the most right element it will always be on the right, even if you have another element right next to the logo, see the added example content.

So my answer is not `better` than the other ones, it just shows a different way to solve your problem. Depending on if you need more elements in a row or not, chose this approach.

```css
.container>* {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .85);
}

.menulinks {
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blueviolet;
  float: left;
}

.menulinks:hover {
  color: coral;
}


/*Added CSS*/

.container {
  display: flex
}

.right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="assets/logo.png" width="150">
  </div>
 <div style="width: 100px; color: white">
   The links are on the right even if here would be another container (with a Slogan, or some other content) 
 </div>

  <div class="right">
    <a href="photos.html" class="menulinks">Photos</a>
    <a href="about.html" class="menulinks">About</a>
    <a href="socials.html" class="menulinks">Socials</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are only two `div`s you could use `display: flex` and the attribute `justify-content: space-between` to put all of the extra space between the only two `div`s.

```css
.container  {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .85);
}

.menulinks {
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blueviolet;
  float: left;
}

.menulinks:hover {
  color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/500/500" width="150">
  </div>

  <div align="right">
    <a href="photos.html" class="menulinks">Photos</a>
    <a href="about.html" class="menulinks">About</a>
    <a href="socials.html" class="menulinks">Socials</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I highly recommend removing your general `*` selector. It is best to be specific when targeting elements.

1. I would assign specific class names to your `div`'s. I chose `item` in my example below.
2. `align="right"` does not work on non-table elements. That is why this is no longer working.
3. Use flexbox! I've added two lines of flexbox code in your container class.

```css
    .container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .item {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .85);
    }
    
    .menulinks{
        font-size: 50px;
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: blueviolet;
        float: left;
    }
    
    .menulinks:hover{
        color: coral;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="assets/logo.png" width="150">
        </div>
    
        <div class="item">
            <a href="photos.html" class="menulinks">Photos</a>
            <a href="about.html" class="menulinks">About</a>
            <a href="socials.html" class="menulinks">Socials</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Different approach with minor adjustment to your existing code is to use `float:right` property to the links.
Worth to mention that the attribute "align" [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551305/align-attribute-deprecated) and all layout design need to be from the style sheet.

What i did is to change the `align="right"` to `class="right"` and then added on the style sheet `.right {float: right;}`.

**Note:** since you giving your links a 50px font-size, on small screen this will span 2 lines. In order to fix this you can add [@media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

**Note(2):** On the break point, i changed a little the `.menulinks` with `font-size: 25px; display: block; float: none;`
So your code can look something like that:

```css
.container > * {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .85);
}

.menulinks {
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blueviolet;
  float: left;
}

.menulinks:hover {
  color: coral;
}
/* added: */
.right {float: right;}
@media (max-height: 480px) { 
  .menulinks {font-size: 25px; display: block; float: none;} 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="assets/logo.png" width="150">
  </div>

  <div class="right"> <!-- change from align="right" that deprecated -->
    <a href="photos.html" class="menulinks">Photos</a>
    <a href="about.html" class="menulinks">About</a>
    <a href="socials.html" class="menulinks">Socials</a>
  </div>
</div>
```