# HTML tags in java Eclipse

Tags: java, html, eclipse

Using Eclipse/java. Some tags obsolete. For example, u, required
Can't find how to exchange and take rid of yellow warnings

```
<h1 align="center">Welcome<span style="color:red" > <%=user1 %>to the website</span></h1>
       <hr>
       <h2 align="left"><u>INTRODUCTION :</u></h2>
       <h3 style="color:green"><%=intro %></h3>
       <hr>
       <h2 align="left"><u>HOBBIES : </u></h2>
       <h3 style="color:green"><%=hobby %></h3>
```

Comment: Yeah, they can be annoying, but it's really part of the Eclipse JSP experience.

Comment: so, just leave it?it is my first project

Comment: I think it's ok, although if you really feel like its a problem, probably just tweak the settings a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Your trying to make your HTML do what CSS was designed to do. Your JSP builds what it thinks the HTML will look like and forwards that to the user. Thus the user never sees the JSP only an HTML page. So when you use the special tags they are done on the server and forwarded to the user.

Deprecation
[Align Attribute Deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551305/align-attribute-deprecated)
To align
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-content.asp

Comment: to align: align-content: center;